# access cell inside a gridview in android

Tags: android

i have kept tags for each of the cell inside a `GridView`. once the gridview is drawn by a custom adapter that i have made, i wish to access one specific cell inside the gridview.

i have tried the following:

```
view = mygridView.findViewWithTag(tag);
```

but the view returned is null. 
how do i access the cell inside the gridview?

thank you in advance.

Comment: You should see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976533/how-to-find-element-inside-a-gridview-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `gridView.getChildAt(i).findViewWithTag(tag);`

Hope it will help.. ;)

Comment: in that case would be nice if u accept it as answer ;) my pleasure.. welcome to android wonderland ;)

Comment: i would have accepted but its not my question so i upvoted only :)

Comment: can u take a llok to my question and ans?? here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994893/gridview-cell-view-position-changes-after-scrolling-color-is-set-to-different

Comment: I always get a null using gridView.getChildAt(i), so I can't invoke findViewWithTag(), but my datagrid is filled with an adapter, it has 4 rows/3 columns, which could be the problem?