# How to find element inside a gridview in Android?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a grid view which I populate using a custom adapter. 
While populating the gridview I give each element inside a unique tag.

Once this gridview is populated, I wish to find a specific element inside the gridview with its tag. How do I find this?

Currently I'm doing this:

```
gridviewobject.findViewById(thetag);
// gridview object is the object of the gridview that i have populated.
```

Comment: If the object is not on-screen then it's view probably does not exist - in that case you cannot get a reference to it. What you can use is `getChildAt` in combination with `getFirstVisiblePosition` and `getChildCount` to determinate which views are currently visible and what position each one corresponds to.

Comment: could you explain in more detail what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you have written above will work, except be aware that a) searching for a view by its tag is probably the slowest method you could use to find a view and b) if you try requesting a view with a tag and that view is not currently visible, then you will get `null`.

This is because `GridView` recycles its views, so essentially it only ever makes enough views to fit on screen, and then just changes the positions and content of these as you scroll about.

Possibly a better way might be to do

```
final int numVisibleChildren = gridView.getChildCount();
final int firstVisiblePosition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

for ( int i = 0; i < numVisibleChildren; i++ ) {
    int positionOfView = firstVisiblePosition + i;

    if (positionOfView == positionIamLookingFor) {
        View view = gridView.getChildAt(i);
    }
}
```

Essentially `findViewWithTag` does something similar, but rather than comparing integers it compares the tags (which is slower since they're objects and not ints)

Comment: i was going for a tag because i did not know the exact location of the view i am trying to find inside the gridview. also when the view is visible, and try to find the view by tag as i have shown in the question i still get a null.

Comment: If each unique position in the GridView has a unique tag then if you know what Tag you are looking for you should also be able to work out what position you are looking for.

Comment: thanks a lot, the code i was reviewing directly accessed childAt(pos).. which resulted in layout null, your code works perfectly...