# Android: how to permanently modify a ListView's child (View) - color gets lost after scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, adapter

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        View v = parent.getChildAt(position);
        TextView fileName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
        fileName.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);


    }
});
```

OnItemClick(), I set the text color of the item's element to blue (file_name).

After scrolling this listview, the new color (blue) is lost (it gets reset to its default color)

Why? Do I have to somehow change the adapter associated with the ListView?

Edit: FileListAdapter (used to populate ListView)

```
package com.landa.adapter;
import java.io.File;


public class FileListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context context;
private final File[] data; 

public FileListAdapter(Context context, File[] values) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

    File f = data[position];

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
    TextView fullPath = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.full_path);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.file_image);

    textView.setText(f.getName());
    fullPath.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
    imageView.setImageResource(
            BrowseHandler.getFileIconResourceId(f.getAbsolutePath()));

    return rowView;

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to change the adapter; to be precise you have to create a custom one by extending ArrayAdapter.

In particular you have to override the `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` to display blue the already clicked items.

Fairly easy, [this tutorial might help](http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/), otherwise ask.

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

Try this way, if it is what you want:

```
public int flag=-1;//CREATE A FLAG TO STORE THE POSITION OF THE ITEM CLICKED

//Other stuff...
//...

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

    View v = parent.getChildAt(position);
    TextView fileName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
    fileName.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    flag=position;//WHIT THIS YOU KEEP TRACK OF THE ITEM THAT WAS CLICKED

}
}); 

//Other stuff...
//...

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

File f = data[position];

TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
TextView fullPath = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.full_path);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.file_image);

//NOW YOU CHECK IF THAT POSTION WAS THE ONE CLICKED, IT SETS THE COLOR BLUE
if(position==flag) textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

textView.setText(f.getName());
fullPath.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageResource(
        BrowseHandler.getFileIconResourceId(f.getAbsolutePath()));

return rowView;

}
```

So basically you use:

`public int flag=-1;`

`flag=position;`

`if(position==flag) textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);`

Comment: Can you elaborate further ? I do have my custom adapter, I'll post it up.

Comment: Based on the tutorial you posted, I identified one problem. Perhaps I shouldn't inflate the view all the time, but only when converView is null.

Comment: @Tool try the code i posted. Shouldn't be difficult to implement. Let me know if it is that what you want. Basically in that way you keep track of 1 (and only 1) of the items already selected.

Comment: Hey. I'm going to try this tomorrow and let you know, thanks for the effort!

Comment: @pietmau- what if i dont use getview i am not extending BaseAdapter see my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994893/gridview-cell-view-position-changes-after-scrolling-color-is-set-to-different) i have tried a lot

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be changing the text colour of the `TextView` within that `onClick` - You should be marking that item within your adapter as clicked - how you do that is up to you.

Once you've marked the item as clicked, you can then notify the `ListView` that the data has changed and it'll refresh the list - during which your `Adapter` can check for the new clicked status and change the colour of the `ListView` appropriately.